# SQL show column of number of duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table like this

How could I sum up the number of similar rows and put that into a new column? I tried to use select distinct but did not give the expected result

Comment: . . Sample data.  Desired results.  An explanation of what YOU mean by duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I didn't misunderstand your question, a simple `count(*)` with a `group by` will do the trick:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM issue_date) AS month,
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM issue_date) AS year, count(*) as n
FROM ticket
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM issue_date), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM issue_date)
ORDER BY year, month;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM issue_date) AS month,
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM issue_date) AS year,
     count(*)
FROM ticket
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM issue_date),EXTRACT(YEAR FROM issue_date)
ORDER BY year, month;
```

Comment: There is no need for `distinct` if you are also using `group by`

Comment: This may answer the question. However, code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.